# sending emails via outlook in mailman

Tags: cpanel, mailman

I have created a mailing list in mailman (CPANEL). When I send emails using the web interface the emails are delivered. When I try to send using Microsoft Outlook 2019, the emails are not delivered. Any idea what I could do to be able to deliver the emails using outlook

Answer (score 0):

I had a client recently working with Microsoft Outlook 2019. The way I solved this issue was by following the cPanel Mail Client Manual Settings:

Username: nickname@your-domain.com (using only the nickname will not work)

Password: your-password

Incoming Server: Here is some config works with mail.your-domain.com and in others with your-domain.com goes through. IMAP Port: 993 POP3L Port 995

Outgoing Server: same config as Incoming Server SMTP Post: 465

I hope it helps.